# Can't right-click with Mighty Mouse on OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, mouse, right-click

I'm using an iMac with OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8 in my office. I don't have a right click option for my Mighty Mouse.

I checked with my System Preferences and I don't have any options to enable "Right Click". I only have Tracking Speed and Double Click Speed options.

[image]

It's a bit tough to use without right click buttons on the mouse when I need to press the Ctrl button all the time.

Comment: i edited my question. Am using a mighty mouse.

Comment: Also which version of Mac are you using? Lion? Snow Leopard?

Comment: snow leopard mac os x with version 10.6.8

Comment: yes. Am using USB mighty mouse, and no additional mouse drivers installed.

Comment: That's really weird. You should be able to see more options in your preference pane. Can you check with another Apple mouse, maybe? Are you *100% sure* you've connected a Mighty Mouse? It should look like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Apple_Wired_and_Wireless_Mighty_Mouse_Bottom_Side_by_Side_Comparison.jpg) at the bottom.

Comment: yes . am 100% damn sure that am using a mighty mouse via usb